# Template assignment operator doesn't replace the default assignment operator

Tags: c++, templates

In *C++ Templates The Complete Guide* in  *section 5.3 Member Templates* it's written:

> Note that a template assignment operator doesn't replace the default
> assignment operator. For assignments of stacks of the same type, the
> default assignment operator is still called.

Is this correct, because when I ran below code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Pair
{
    public:
            T pair1,pair2;
            Pair(T i,T j):pair1(i),pair2(j){}
            template<typename T1>Pair<T>& operator=(Pair<T1>&);             
};

template<typename T>
template<typename T1>
Pair<T>& Pair<T>::operator=(Pair<T1>& temp)
{
    
    this->pair1 =temp.pair1*10;//At this point
    this->pair2=temp.pair2;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    
    Pair<int>P1(10,20);
    Pair<int>P2(1,2);
    P2=P1;
    cout<<P2.pair1<<' '<<P2.pair2<<endl;
    return 1;
}
```

I got answer 100 20.

It didn't give the default assignment answer.

Is that a typing mistake in *C++ Templates the Complete Guide*?

> C++ Templates: The Complete Guide By David Vandevoorde, Nicolai M.
> Josuttis
>
> Publisher : Addison Wesley
>
> Pub Date : November 12, 2002  Pages : 552

Comment: I think `Pair<T1>& temp` doesn't involve a const qualification when a non-const lvalue is passed in, so it's a better conversion sequence

Comment: Both assignment operators exist in `Pair`, and participate in overload resolution. Because the templated one takes non-const reference, while the implicitly declared one takes a const reference, the former is a better match in this case. Once you change the templated one to take a const reference, the implicitly defined one gets called as you expected. [Live example](http://rextester.com/DDFQFL78519)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The copy assignment operator is indeed implicitly declared and considered by overload resolution.

> A user-declared copy assignment operator `X::operator=` is a
>   non-static **non-template member function** of class `X` [..]. 
> **If the class definition does not explicitly
>   declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared *implicitly***. [..]
>   The implicitly-declared copy assignment operator for a class `X` will
>   have the form
>
> ```
> X& X::operator=(const X&)
> ```
>
> if
>
> - each direct base class `B` of `X` has a copy assignment operator whose parameter is of type `const B&`, `const volatile B&` or `B`, and
> - for all the non-static data members of `X` that are of a class type `M` (or array thereof), each such class type has a copy assignment
>     operator whose parameter is of type `const M&`, `const volatile M&` or
>     `M`.
>
> Otherwise, [..]

As you can see the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator for `Pair<int>` has one parameter of type `Pair<int> const&` - note the `const` in particular! Overload resolution favours non-`const` references over `const` ones if both can be bound to the argument, [over.ics.rank]/3:

> Two implicit conversion sequences of the same form are
>   indistinguishable conversion sequences unless one of the following
>   rules applies:
>
> —
>    Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence
>   `S2` if
>
> - [..]
> - `S1` and `S2` are reference bindings (8.5.3), and the types to which the
>     references refer are the same type except for top-level cv-qualifiers,
>     **and the type to which the reference initialized by `S2` refers is more
>     cv-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by `S1`
>     refers.**

The specialization of the template lacks a `const` in the reference parameter, thus it's a better match and is selected.

Answer (score 6):

The default assignment operator accepts the argument as a const reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator.

You have defined a version without `const`, and your version is better in the context of overload resolution (no conversion required).

Try with [the following change](http://ideone.com/FC7Oyi):

```
int main()
{
    Pair<int>P1(10,20);
    Pair<int>P2(1,2);
    const Pair<int>& x = P1;
    P2=x;
    cout<<P2.pair1<<' '<<P2.pair2<<endl;
    return 1;
}
```

to see the expected result.